# How to do real-time checking of the compression ratio of tsfiles in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: compression, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to check the compression ratio of tsfile in real time in Apache IoTDB? My editor currently returns 1 when I did query on certain tsfiles, does this number means that no compression is taking place?

Answer (score 0):

The compression ratio can be checked from the file which under a folder of Apache-IoTDB named 'datanode/system/compression_ratio'.In this folder,there is a file named as 'Compression-{number1}-{number2}'.
{number1} means 'the size before compression';
{number2} means 'the size after compression'.
Example : Compression-123456789-12345678

The number returned from your editor should represents the number of rows of the result queried,and has nothing to do with your compression ratio of Apache-IoTDB.